# Can Bitmap objects be added into a Bitmap array in android?

Tags: android, bitmapimage

Can I add Bitmap objects into Bitmap array in android, while trying to do that could find that there was no specific methods available for it.Any Help from any one would be highly appreciable. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: post your code how you did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [ArrayList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of plain Array

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Bitmap [] bitmapArray = new Bitmap[size];

for(int i = 0; i < bitmapArray.length; i++)
    bitmapArray[i] = your_bitmap_object;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But i want to add multiple bitmap objects into a single bitmap array(not a single object).